# High server load for index.php Wordpress website

Tags: performance, server, load, database-performance, vps

I need help... There's this wordpress website on a VPS. When there are many active users, the index.php file causes big server load. This is the website http://top6.com/ . I scanned the plugins and only two plugins seem to cause high load - Social Network Auto Poster and SEO by Yoast, but I don't think they are the problem. I need some tips on what can be done here... where to start from, how to indicate what's causing this problem in first place? Even if I disable all the plugins and switch the theme, how do I know the issue is fixed? I don't have access to the server... I only have access to FTP and wordpress admin panel. I installed w3total cache plugins, configured it too... doesn't seem to help. I also optimized the images, installed some images optimizing plugins... still nothing. The traffic should not be causing the problem too, because the system has high parameters and handles that kind of traffic... Any help will be much appreciated...

Comment: when you say high server load, does it mean high CPU or Memory? Can you get some metrics from the server?

Comment: the client provided me an image saying 44%CPU ; 0.07 Memory

Comment: 44% CPU is not a big server load

Comment: well I don't have server based knowledge... but my client claims he shouldn't get that kind of server load. He believes some kind of plugin causes the problem... can you make the picture more clear for me? Is there anything I can do anyway? I am an SEO optimizer and I don't really know how to answer to his request to reduce the server load when I even don't have a clue what's causing it...

Comment: Can you at least share how to keep an eye on the server load in real-time? If I have access to the cpanel will I be able to? Never worked on wordpress that's on vps before and don't have any idea... I can request access to the cpanel if that will do it, then I can try deactivating some plugins and check out if there's any improvement...